# What is the "global keymap" in zsh?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, zle

In the `zsh` manual [18.2.2 Local Keymaps](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Local-Keymaps) it refers to the "global keymap" thrice.

Where is this term defined?

How do I find out what is my current global keymap, and how would I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line editor has a global keymap active at any time. This is normally the `emacs` keymap when using Emacs mode, or either `viins` or `vicmd` when using Vi mode. You can select a different one with `zle -K` or via `vared {-M,-m}`. When executing widget code, the name of the global keymap is available as [`$KEYMAP`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-KEYMAP).

The local keymap, if any, overrides bindings of the global keymap. It's used internally by some widgets such as incremental search, `M-x`, etc. I don't think it can be set directly from zsh code.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that a `s/global keymap/main keymap/` in the manual would be an upgrade :)

Comment: @TomHale The global keymap isn't always `main`. For example, it's `vicmd` when in Vi command mode.